# Delphi Firemonkey get/set TBitmap through RTTI

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tbitmap

How can I get/set TBitmap through RTTI? I have done as following:

```
function TMyWebCam.BitmapToString: string;
var
  RContext : TRttiContext;
  RType: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  value : TValue;
begin
  RContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  RType := RContext.GetType(ClassType);
  prop := RType.GetProperty('screenshot');
  prop.GetValue(Self).TryCast(TypeInfo(TBitmap), value);
  Result := value.ToString;
end;
```

which gives me: (TBitmapOfItem @ 07A06280)
For converting string to TBitmap have done as following:

```
procedure TMyWebCam.SetScreenshot(AString: String);
var
  RContext : TRttiContext;
  RType: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  value : TValue;
begin
  RContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  RType := RContext.GetType(ClassType);
  prop := RType.GetProperty('screenshot');
  value.Cast(TypeInfo(TBitmap));
  value.From<String>(AString);
  prop.SetValue(Self, value);
end;
```

This is my class

```
  TMyWebCam = class
  private
    fscreenshot: TBitmap;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;override;
    property screenshot: TBitmap read fscreenshot write fscreenshot;
    function BitmapToString : string;
    procedure SetScreenshot(AString : String);
  end;

constructor TMyWebCam.Create;
begin
  fscreenshot := TBitmap.Create;
end;

destructor TMyWebCam.Destroy;
begin
  fscreenshot.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

I have to convert TBitmap to string for passing it to another client as Broadcast message.

Comment: Even if you could retrieve the `TBitmap` via RTTI (which is useless to do inside the same class that already has a direct pointer to the `TBitmap`), why would you think letting RTTI convert it to a string would be a meaningful operation for transmitting it? It is not. RTTI simply converts an object to a string representation of the object's memory address, which is what you are seeing. For transmission, you need to serialize the image data instead. For instance, save the `TBitmap` to a `TMemoryStream` and encode the resulting bytes to base64, then transmit that string. Reverse on the receiver.

Comment: Encoding to base64 string size is huge, this is why I tried to use RTTI. I am trying to do a Datasnap TDSAdminClient's BroadcastToChannel. The sender got hanged during sending to other clients.

Comment: Ok Remy, how can I revert the following function's result back to TBitmap:

function BitmapToBase64(Bitmap: Tbitmap): string;
var
  BS: TBitmapSurface;
  AStream: TStringStream;
begin
  BS := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  BS.Assign(Bitmap);
  BS.SetSize(300, 200);
  AStream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(AStream, BS, '.png');
    Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(AStream.DataString)
  finally
    AStream.Free;
    BS.Free;
  end;
end;

Comment: there are other binary-to-string formats available that are more condensed than base64, such as yEnc. Or consider using compression. The point is, what you are attempting to do with RTTI is not feisible or appropriate for what you are attempting to do with your broadcasts. You need serialization instead.

Comment: you should not be saving the Bitmap to a `TStringStream`, it is not string data. Use a `TMemoryStream` instead, then use `TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream()`. On the other side, use `TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream()` to decode into a `TMemoryStream`, then load that into a Bitmap. I'm not familiar with DataSnap, do you really have to broadcast data as a string? Can't you broadcast binary data instead?

Comment: TDSAdminClient has BroadcastObjectToChannel which broadcast TObject. I tried but got AV "Internal: Type tkInterface is not currently supported". This is why I am trying as string. This is what I am passing MyWebCam.screenshot := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(ms); as I changed TBitmap to string.

Comment: `BroadcastToChannel()` takes a `TJSONValue`, not a `String`. If `BroadcastObjectToObject()` treats an object as an interface and fails then that is a bug that should be reported to Quality Portal.

Comment: this is how I am doing:
const
  MYCAMERA = 'broadcastmycamera:%s,user:%s,room:%s,camera:%s';

var
  val: TJSONString;
begin
  val := TJSONString.Create(Format(MYCAMERA, [MyAccountInfo.id.ToString,
    MyAccountInfo.login_name, ARoom, MyWebCam.screenshot]));
  wscDataModule.BroadcastToChannel(val);
end;

as I need which user is viewing for which user's webcamera, I have to pass those value

Comment: I would suggest using a `TJSONObject` to break up all those values into actual name/value pairs, instead of stuffing everything into a single `TJSONString` (and get of `Format()`). You are not using JSON the way it is intended to be used.

Comment: `var obj: TJSONObject; obj := TJSONObject.Create;obj.AddPair('camera',MyAccountInfo.id.ToString); obj.AddPair('user',MyAccountInfo.login_name); obj.AddPair('room',ARoom); obj.AddPair('image','base64bitmap'); wscDataModule.BroadcastToChannel(obj);`

Comment: I found a way, there is a overload method for broadcast with TObject which I didn't see it in the first place. So with that method I can broadcast any type of TObject. Thanks for your help. I did change TJSONString to TJSONObject.